# Check image src is valid when setting

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I have a small piece of noddy code, when clicking an image the user can change the source.  This is the function I use

```
function doStuff(objId){
        newVal = prompt("new Value")
        if(newVal==""){
            newVal = "blank"
        }
    document.getElementById(objId).src=newVal+".png"
}
```

Is there a way to check before setting the src if that is a valid filename at the same point as when I check if the user has not specified anything?  I'd like to be able to protect the page so if the user types "banana" and there is no banana.png available that I just change it to the blank.png file.

I've found various methods for doing it on error but wasn't sure how to do it in this instance as none of those seem to trigger if the page is being updated dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: Send an AJAX HEAD request to check whether the image is present before setting the `src` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modify the `img` tag to show the default image on error

`<img onerror="this.src='images/default.jpg'"/>`

now you can execute you function to change image dynamically

```
function doStuff(objId){
        newVal = prompt("new Value")
        if(newVal==""){
            newVal = "blank"
        }
    document.getElementById(objId).src=newVal+".png"
}
```

**attached a snippet below which changes images dynamically, if not found load the default image**

```js
var server = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/';

function changeImage(option) {
  
  document.getElementById('test').src = server + option.value;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <img width='150' height='150' id='test' src="http://www.yostra.com/images/team/you.png" onerror="this.src='http://www.yostra.com/images/team/you.png'" />
  <br>
  <select onchange='changeImage(this)'>
  <option>--Choose--</option>
    <option value='airplane.png'>airplane.png</option>
    <option value='baboon.png'>baboon.png</option>
    <option value='abs'>ABC</option>
    <option value='arctichare.png'>arctichare.png</option>
    <option value=''>----</option>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, edited your question to remove the `javascript:` from the attribute. Not sure if that even works in that place, I know it only from `<a href="javascript:foo()">` situations, but even if it does, it serves no actual purpose here. Other than that, good answer, +1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, I have put this in to my source <img id = "1" class = "smallimage" src="blank.png" onclick = "doStuff(this.id)" onerror="this.src='blank.png'"> but when I click it and enter a value of "banana" (and there is no banana.png) I still get a broken link :/

Comment: Looking at the developer console I can see an error stating "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: Ignore my previous comments I was a total idiot and this works like a charm! cheers!